Can I mount a tv to straight up drywall
Using a full-motion mount, I have a wall where my 55 inch 30lb tv will be mounted. There are 2 studs but 1 is an inch from a doorframe so not unusable.
The plan is to use 4 137b support toggle bolts in the drywall. Here are my questions:

Would this plan be fine since the tv isn't heavy?
is a full-motion mount a good idea and if the answers no, what about a flat mount?
could I just use 1 stud that is slightly off center for the full-motion mount?

Materials
Tv mount

I can't find a link but the package says they hold 137 lb on 1/2 inch drywall.

Studs should be ~every 16 inches.  If the studs are not in a good place for your mount, then can screw plywood/1x6s across the studs and then mount the tv.

@crip659 I've seen videos of that but don't have the tools to remove drywall.

@IvanDraga - you don't remove the drywall, you mount the plywood or other wood on top of the drywall. Bonus points from your spouse for paining to match. The plywood screws to studs, and can be wide enough to hit 3 or more. The TV mount then screws into the plywood wherever it looks right to you. You have decoupled the TV mount location from the stud location.

I wouldn't trust any drywall anchors to hold 137 pounds per anchor, especially with a full-motion mount.  It may hold for a while, but as you move the mount, it'll put a lot of stress on the back of the drywall through the bolt and anchor, loosening the anchor and eventually pulling out or pulling whole sections of the drywall.  You must make sure it's anchored into studs (or as other posters have recommended, use a good sized sheet of painted plywood to anchor to multiple studs, then screw your mount to that.

Full motion mounts put a lot of stress on the wall.  Those toggles might be okay for mounting the tv straight/solid to the wall, but it is expensive so I would want studs/solid wood to mount to.  Drywall is perfect for paint, but it is not structural.

Quite certain those anchors would hold 137 pounds or more.  The problem is the drywall will probably not hold those bolts in.  Take a piece of drywall in your hand and just squeeze/bend.  Now do you trust drywall to hold your expensive tv.

@IvanDraga Note that the manufacturer's specifications show 74# in tension, 137# in shear. Since the TV will be extended from the wall and moved around it will be more of a live tension load.

See past answers about mounting flat screen TVs. Sometimes the right answer is to mount a piece of (ply)wood, and then mount the TV to that. Whether you can get away with a single stud depends on the weight of the TV and the stresses you expect to put on it; a large screen or a swiveling mount really do want two studs.

Also Can I hang a TV with one stud and drywall anchors?, Mounting Full Motion Mount on a Single Stud, Mount a fully articulated tv mount with only one stud, ...

NO, JUST NO
I wouldn't recommend this in general. I especially don't recommend it with a full motion mount. Why? Because in addition to various engineering calculations that will tell you how 30 lbs. becomes some larger amount in some aspect (I don't understand all the math, but trust me on this), there is a huge problem that people will, despite their claims to the contrary, inevitably pull on the TV stressing the mounting hardware far more than the 30 lb. weight would imply.
Just don't do this.
Studs should be every 16". Possibly every 24". If you really truly can't get the mount to hit two studs then you have other options:

Cut open the drywall. Add some 2x4 cross-pieces between studs at the height of the TV mount. Replace the drywall. Patch and paint. Install the TV mount to the cross-pieces.
Cut a piece of plywood to span at least two studs. Mount it to the studs. Paint it to match the drywall, assuming at least some of the plywood would be visible with the TV mount and TV installed. Install the TV mount on the plywood.


I'd appreciate some help avoiding obvious duplicates.
